# How can I program an animated sequence of strings in JavaScript (with fade effect)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got the following code that loops through the array and periodically replaces the contents of a div with id "sequence".

```
<script>
    var example = ['A','B','C','D'];

    textSequence(0);
    function textSequence(i) {

        if (example.length > i) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById("sequence").innerHTML = "We Do " + example[i];
                textSequence(++i);

            }, 3000); // 1 second (in milliseconds)

        } else if (example.length == i) { // Loop
            textSequence(0);
        }

    }
</script>
```

The div:

```
<div id="sequence" style="font-family: Roboto; font-size: 48px;">...</div>
```

**Runnable demo:**

```js
var example = ['A','B','C','D'];

textSequence(0);
function textSequence(i) {

    if (example.length > i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("sequence").innerHTML = "We Do " + example[i];
            textSequence(++i);

        }, 3000); // 1 second (in milliseconds)

    } else if (example.length == i) { // Loop
        textSequence(0);
    }

}
```

```html
<div id="sequence" style="font-family: Roboto; font-size: 48px;">...</div>
```

At this stage, I'd like to fade out each string, and then fade in each new one in the array. Is it possible to accomplish this using CSS by fading the div to 0 and 1 at the end and beginning of each sequence?

Comment: @ChrisG OP did provide a **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**. Didn't you see it? (I'm not talking about the snippet I added either).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I should have been clearer but I was talking about the future attempt at implementing fading (and using a snippet)

Comment: @ChrisG There is nothing wrong with the question. OP provided MCVE, showed us what he got so far. And the styling is superb. Rare are the questions that are this clear and straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with css animations where the time of animation is half of the interval of change of array elements. Then you also add `infinite` and `alternate` properties.

```js
const example = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
const div = document.getElementById('sequence');
let i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  div.innerHTML = "We Do " + `<span>${example[i++ % example.length]}</span>`
}, 3000)
```

```css
#sequence span {
  animation: change_opacity 1.5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes change_opacity {
  0% {opacity: 0}
  100% {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<div id="sequence" style="font-family: Roboto; font-size: 48px;">...</div>
```

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I noticed this as well. The second parameter for ``setInterval`` should be double (in milliseconds) the CSS animation time (after ``change_opacity), to account for the time that the text fades in and out.

Comment: Yes as I said `the time of animation is half of the interval of change of array elements`, so if the interval in js is set to 3000 or 3s then we set 1.5s in css because 1.5s is for 0 - 100% change in opacity and another 1.5s is for 100% - 0 change and this happens because of `alternate`,  then array change happens etc...

Comment: You could do the same without `alternate` and using same time in js and in css like this https://jsfiddle.net/5hxc40m4/1/